# Keep string up to first occurrence of pattern in R

Tags: regex, r, string, text, gsub

I would like to keep the string up to the first occurrence of the following pattern: lower case letter followed by upper case, followed by lower case again.

For example

```
"This is My testString, how to keepUntil test"
```

I would like to return `This is My test`

This is what I have tried unsuccessfully so far:

```
library("magrittr")

"This is My testString, how to keepUntil test" %>% gsub("(.*[a-z])[A-Z][a-z]?.*", "\\1", .)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `strsplit`

```
strsplit(str1, "(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])", perl = TRUE)[[1]][1]
#[1] "This is My test"
```

or with `sub`

```
sub("([A-Za-z ]+[a-z])[A-Z].*", "\\1", str1)
#[1] "This is My test"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "This is My testString, how to keepUntil test"
```

Comment: Thanks akrun, greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive function with regex capturing groups to extract always the first (leftmost) instance of the pattern you want, regardless of how many sections your text has.

```
regex <- "^(.*[a-z])[A-Z].*$"
text <- "This is My testString, how to keepUntil test"

library(stringr)

ExtractFirstPart <- function(Text,Regex) {
  firstpart <- str_match(Text,Regex)[2]
  if (is.na(firstpart)) {
    return(Text)
  } else {
    firstpart <- ExtractFirstPart(firstpart,Regex)
    return(firstpart)
  }
}
```

Using this function, you will get:

```
> ExtractFirstPart(text,regex)
[1] "This is My test"
```